# "esqueci" or "me esqueci"?

Tags: gramática, pronomes-reflexivos

**In ptBR you are likely to hear "eu me esqueci" just as often as "eu esqueci", when "esquecer" is used with an indirect object.**  Literally, "eu me esqueci" would mean that "I forgot myself", but it is used in the same contexts and with the same meaning as "eu esqueci"

These examples are all current usage in ptBR:

- "Eu esqueci de dizer..."/"Eu me esqueci de dizer..."
- "Você não foi ao encontro?" "Ah, eu me esqueci que tinha prometido ir."/"Ah, eu esqueci que tinha..."

**When esquecer is used with a direct object, however, there is no doubt and nobody adds a reflexive pronoun.**

- Eu esqueci as chaves em casa.
- Ela esqueceu tudo.  Não lembra de nada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Todas estas formas estão corretas:

> (1) Eu esqueci tudo.
>   (2) Eu esqueci-me de tudo.
>   (3) Eu esqueci de tudo.

Esta conclusão pode ser logo tirada do primeiro significado de "esquecer" no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/esquecer):

> 1. Perder da memória, da lembrança (alguém ou algo); não (se) lembrar; OLVIDAR [td.: *Nunca esqueci o meu primeiro amor*: *"Nunca me esquecerei que no meio do caminho tinha uma pedra"* (Carlos Drummond de Andrade , "No meio do caminho") ] [int.: *Viajou para esquecer*] [tr. + de: *Não (me) esqueço da minha primeira boneca*]

No entanto, posso dizer que em Portugal seria muito estranho ouvir (3), e seria mais provável que "de" fosse interpretado com função partitiva (="eu esqueci de tudo qualquer coisa"). Parece ser mais comum no Brasil. No entanto, consegui encontrar alguns exemplos no CETEMPúblico:

> Corajoso é o que esquece de fugir?
>   «Vinte anos depois da sua morte, Lubitsch faz ainda parte daqueles autores que esquecemos de citar entre os grandes, reconhecendo-o...

Também é possível ***esqueceu-me tudo*** (sendo *tudo* o sujeito gramatical), com significado igual a (2), mas o seu uso está restrito à oralidade.

De resto, (1) e (2) não têm necessariamente o mesmo sentido. Citando outra vez o Aulete:

> 4. Descuidar(-se), distrair(-se) [tr. + de: *Andava rápido, sem (se) esquecer de sorrir para os conhecidos*]

Neste sentido, não é possível omitir "de". Assim, estas duas frases podem ter interpretações distintas:

> (4) Não me esqueci dela.
>   (5) Não a esqueci.

Se eu tinha um encontro com alguém e estiver a assegurar uma terceira pessoa de que tenho tudo sob controlo e de que temos tempo para a ir buscar, só posso usar (4). Se eu em certa altura distante tiver conhecido dada pessoa que dalguma forma me marcou e quiser realçá-lo, então a melhor opção é (5), embora (4) também seja possível.

Answer (score 2):

Isto é apenas para complementar a resposta do Artefacto. O dicionário Huaiss (Lisboa, 2002) confirma que as construções dos vários exemplos apresentados na pergunta estão em uso no Brasil, mas acrescenta que a construção *esquecer de* (do exemplo *esqueci de dizer*) é condenada por alguns gramáticos; Citando do verbete *esquecer* (negrito meu):

> […] a construção ***esquecer de*** (*algo ou de fazer algo*) é comum na língua falada coloquial brasileira e também muito usada na literatura escrita, embora alguns gramáticos a condenem (p.ex.: ***esqueci do seu livro; esqueci de comprar os bilhetes***)

A *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014) concorda e apresenta o assunto de forma mais sistemática. Basicamente, o verbo *esquecer* tem atualmente três regências transitivas em uso corrente no Brasil. Usando os exemplos dos autores:

> (a) **Esqueci** os deveres religiosos
>
> (b) **Esqueci-me d**os deveres religiosos
>
> (c) **Esqueci d**os deveres religiosos

Nestes exemplos o objeto do verbo é, para maior clareza das diferenças entre as regências, uma expressão nominal (*os deveres religiosos*), mas o objeto pode ser também uma oração subordinada substantiva finita (*que tenho deveres*) ou infinita (*cumprir os deveres*), que é o que encontramos nos primeiros exemplos da pergunta.

***Eu esqueci de dizer*** e ***eu me esqueci de dizer*** seguem respetivamente as regências (c) e (b). A regência (c), *esquecer de*, é segundo Cunha e Cintra (p. 652) muito frequentemente usada com orações infinitivas deste tipo.

***Eu me esqueci que tinha prometido ir***, podendo não parecer à primeira vista, segue a regência (b). O que acontece é que nestes casos—não só com o verbo *esquecer*, mas com muitos outros também—a preposição é opcional e é frequentemente omitida; mas “ressuscita” obrigatoriamente quando a oração é substituída por uma expressão nominal:

> Eu me esqueci (de) que tinha prometido ir ao encontro
>
> Eu me esqueci **da** minha promessa/**d**isso

A *Nova Gramática* (p. 652) nota isso mesmo, que “não é raro na língua atual o tipo sintático *esquecer que*, com elipse da preposição. Na minha experiência pessoal, aqui em Portugal, esta preposição é quase sempre omitida na linguagem não formal.

***Eu esqueci que tinha prometido ir*** pode em abstrato ser vista como seguindo a regência (a) ou a regência (c) com a elipse da preposição comum nestes casos.

As regências (a) e (b)—*esquecer* e *esquecer-se de*—são as tradicionais, e em Portugal são as únicas em uso corrente. Segundo a *Nova Gramática* (p. 652) a regência (c), *esquecer de*, resultou do cruzamento das outras e acrescentam:

> Tal construção, considerada viciosa pelos gramáticos, mas muito frequente no colóquio brasileiro, já se vem insinuando na linguagem literária, principalmente quando o complemento de *esquecer* é um infinitivo. Sirvam de exemplo estes passos:
>
> Guma **esquece de tudo**, e se deixa ir no doce acalanto dessa toada tão bela. (Jorge Amado, [*Mar Morto,*] 55.)
>
> Ah, sim, **esqueci de confessar** quando a vi. (Nélida Piñon, [*Sala de Armas,*] 155.)

Nem o Houaiss nem Cunha e Cintra nomeiam os gramáticos críticos, mas a posição destes é a que aparece em tudo quanto é site brasileiro de como falar bom português, como [Guia do Estudante](https://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/blog/duvidas-portugues/esquecer-algo-ou-esquecer-de-algo/), [Recanto das Letras](https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/788625), [Dicas de Português](https://www.tjsc.jus.br/web/servidor/dicas-de-portugues/-/asset_publisher/0rjJEBzj2Oes/content/prevencao-em-saude-bucal), [Linguativa](http://www.linguativa.com.br/laphp/conteudo/tipoDicionario.php?categoriaPrograma=2024&chamada=39073) ou este [Learn Portuguese no YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xwwss7v24Y). Isto é provavelmente uma coisa a ter em atenção nos concursos e exames oficiais.

Também a regência (a) já foi condenado como galicismo por puristas (Houaiss), mas já há quase duzentos anos [Fr. Francisco de São Luiz (*Glossario...*, 1827, p. 55)](https://archive.org/stream/glossariodaspal00luizgoog#page/n65/mode/2up) demostrou a ignorância de um desses puristas, que supunha “que em bom portuguez sómente se póde dizer *esqueci-me da lição,* ou *esqueceo-me a lição*, e não *esqueci a lição.* É que esta construção já era usada por Camões e outros clássicos.

Desta outra construção mencionada por Fr. São Luiz—“*esqueceu-me a lição*”—diz o Houaiss que é hoje pouco usada e própria da linguagem formal. Construções deste tipo não me soam estranhas, mas, em sintonia com o que observa o Artefacto, eu associo-as não à linguagem formal, mas à popular; a única memória concreta que tenho dela é um aforismo que o meu pai costumava dizer:

> Há coisas que esquecem muito a quem não sabe.

**Pronomes reflexos vs. pronomes inerentes**. Palavra por palavra, *eu me esqueci* traduz-se para *I forgot myself*, mas o pronome átono aqui não tem função reflexa (não indica que a ação recai sobre o próprio sujeito), é antes inerente ao verbo. Existem muitos verbos destes em português, como *arrepender-se, rir-se,* etc (ver [esta pergunta sobre *arrepender-se*)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/arrepender-se-%C3%A9-um-verbo-reflexivo). Podemos distinguir as duas funções do pronome, vendo que este pode ser reforçado com *a mim/ti/si mesmo* no caso da função reflexa (*vesti-me a mim mesmo*) mas não na função inerente: não se pode dizer *esqueci-me a mim mesmo da lição*. Se quisermos dizer que uma pessoa se esquece a ela mesma, a forma mais usual é com o modelo (b) (imagino que também com (c) no Brasil):

> Um altruísta, que se esquece de si mesmo e só pensa nos outros.

**Usos dos vários modelos**. O Artefacto tem uma nota sobre isto, e eu tenho uma resposta relativamente desenvolvida a [esta pergunta sobre esse assunto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/the-real-meaning-of-esquecer).

Comment: Como verbo transitivo direto, nunca ouvi os exemplos (b) e (c).  O exemplo (a) é de uso corrente por aqui.  Mas a pergunta é sobre esquecer como verbo transitivo indireto.

Comment: Acho que não serve de nada traduzir literalmente ao inglês. Alias, "Eu me esqueci do nome dele" e "Eu esqueci o nome dele." se traduzem da mesma maneira.

Comment: @Centaurus, mas "esquecer" nos meus exemplos (b) e (c) é transitivo indireto!

Comment: @Lambie, é verdade, mas o ponto aqui é que *me esqueci* neste exemplos **não** é reflexo, ou seja não é equivalente a *I forgot myself*. Escrevi assim, pegando na maneira como o assunto foi apresentado na pergunta.

Comment: @Lambie Claro, não discordo. Não vejo porque ajuda apresentar a tradução. Em todo caso, I forgot myself quer dizer ser mal educado. :)

Comment: @Lambie, na pergunta vem "Literally, "eu me esqueci" would mean that "I forgot myself", e eu peguei nisso e comentei.

Comment: @Jacinto  Tens razão.  Então, corrigindo, como formas variantes de "esqueci a senha", nunca ouvi os exemplos (b) e (c) por aqui. E a pergunta não é exatamente sobre esse uso.

Comment: «Desta outra construção mencionada por Fr. São Luiz—“esqueceu-me a lição”—diz o Houaiss que é hoje pouco usada e própria da linguagem formal.» A minha experiência é precisamente a contrária, que é usado apenas na linguagem oral (ou textos antigos). Ouve-se ainda bastante entre algumas pessoas mais velhas, como o meu avô (idem para lembrar: "não me lembra").

Comment: @Centaurus, as construções usadas nos meus três exemplos com "a senha"--*esquecer, esquecer-se de* e *esquecer de*--são as mesmas que aparecem nos teus exemplos; simplesmente tu tens complementos oracionais. É normal apresentar as várias construções com expressões nominais como "senha" ou "tudo" (na resposta do Artefacto) para maior clareza. Não pensei que isto levantasse dificuldades, até porque não pareceu levantar na resposta do Artefacto. Mas expliquei na última edição a ligação entre os meus exemplos básicos e os teu exemplos.

Comment: @Artefacto, eu também não me lembro de ver essa construção na linguagem formal. Talvez seja assim no Brasil. À exceção do "coisas que esquecem a quem não sabe", da linguagem popular, não me lembro de exemplos concretos dessa construção. O que me surge mais facilmente na cabeça são coisas como "já me esquecia que..." que também pode ser "(eu) já me esquecia (de) que..." com o "de" omisso.

Comment: Ok, Jacinto, entendo.  Eu só quis dizer que minha pergunta não abrange os teus exemplos (b) e (c) simplesmente porque nunca os ouvi antes.  Só por isso.