# "arrepender-se" é um verbo reflexivo?

Tags: verbos, pronomes-reflexivos

**Verbos reflexivos são aqueles cuja ação verbal reflete no próprio sujeito que a pratica**, e são sempre acompanhados de um pronome átono.  Exemplos: "Ela penteou-se", "João lavou-se pela manhã", "Maria entregou-se ao amante". **Podemos classificar "arrepender-se como um verbo reflexivo?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O verbo é reflexo [quando *se* é um pronome reflexo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/verbo-reflexivo--pronome-reflexivo/15756). Para o ser, teria de ter uma função de complemento direto (ou mais raramente, indireto) e referir-se a um sintagma nominal com função de sujeito na mesma oração, com o qual concordasse em género e número.

Portanto, nestas frases:

> (1) Ela **penteou-se**.
>   (2) João **lavou-se** pela manhã.
>   (3) Maria **entregou-se** ao amante.

Em todas elas, *se* refere-se ao sujeito e é um pronome reflexo. Podemos adicionar *a si próprio/a* como reforço pleonástico do complemento direto.

Já nestoutra:

> (4) Ele **arrependeu-se** amargamente.

podemos apenas falar de uma **conjugação reflexa ou pronominal**; não se trata de uma oração reflexa. Repara ainda que não podemos dizer:

> (5) *Ele **arrependeu-se** amargamente **a si mesmo**.

*Arrepender-se* pode ser classificado como um verbo intransitivo inacusativo. Sobre este tipo de verbos diz a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (2013, p. 1206) o seguinte:

> Digno de nota é o facto de muitos verbos inacusativos (incluindo a maioria dos verbos de alternância causativa-incoativa, quando são usados intransitivamente) serem intrinsecamente pronominais, isto é, usam-se orbigatoriamente com um pronome do paradigma dos pronomes reflexos. A este uso, a gramática tradicional chama "conjugação pronominal" ou "conjugação reflexa".

Answer (score 3):

***Arrepender-se*** não é um verbo reflexivo: o verbo não descreve uma ação que incida sobre quem a pratica. O ***se*** é neste caso classificado no [Infoescola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/se-particula-apassivadora-ou-indice-de-indeterminacao-do-sujeito/) como uma partícula sem função sintática ou morfológica que é parte integrante do verbo. O verbo é ***arrepender-se*** e não simplesmente *arrepender*. O verbo pode ser intransitivo:

> O João ia falar com o patrão, mas à última da hora ***arrependeu-se***.

Ou pode ser transitivo com a preposição de:

> ***Arrependeu-se*** do que tinha feito.

Em nenhum dos casos o objeto do arrependimento é o próprio autor da ação.

Normalmente (não ouso dizer sempre) um verbo reflexivo é também transitivo direto. A diferença reside em a ação incidir sobre algo diferente do seu autor ou incidir sobre o próprio autor. É o que se passa nos exemplos dos verbos reflexivos na pergunta:

> Eu penteio o João (transitivo direto); eu penteio-me (reflexivo).
>
> O João lava o carro (transitivo direto); o João lava-se (reflexivo).
>
> A Maria entregou a sua vida ao amante (transitivo direto); A Maria entregou-se ao amante (reflexivo).

Comment: "à última **da** hora" ? Is it a typo or really current ptPT?

Comment: É mesmo assim que dizemos.

Comment: I mean, I had never heard that and, in ptBR, we say "na última hora".

Comment: Também se diz por cá *à última hora*. O ciberdúvidas condena *à última da hora*, mas um outro site diz que é aceitável. Talvez valha a pena abrir uma pergunta sobre isto.