# "se suicidar" é redundante?

Tags: gramática

"Suicidar" significa "se matar", "tirar a própria vida".

Logo, falar "fulano se suicidou" seria redundante? Me parece (estou certo?) ser o mesmo que falar "fulano se se matou".

Porém falar "fulano suicidou" também fica estranho, está correta? Se não, qual seria a forma correta?

Comment: Sim, é redundante, mas há redundâncias que fazem parte da língua.

Comment: Todo mundo fala assim.  Fazer o que?  O uso popular consagra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Suicidar-se*** ou ***se suicidar*** está correto e não é redundante. A questão é que em português o verbo *suicidar* não existe (não o encontras nos melhores dicionários, como o Houaiss ou o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/suicidar)); o que existe é [*suicidar-se* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/suicidar-se) , e o ***se*** aqui não tem função reflexa—é antes um pronome inerente; faz parte do verbo, à semelhança de *rir-se* ou *queixar-se*. Cito a *Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 510-12; negrito meu):

> Muitos verbos são conjugados com pronomes átonos, à semelhança dos reflexivos, sem que tenham exatamente o seu sentido. São os chamados VERBOS PRONOMINAIS, de que podemos distinguir dois tipos:
>
> *a*) os que só se usam na forma pronominal, como:
>
> apiedar-se, queixar-se, condoer-se, **suicidar-se**
>
> [...]
>
> O PRONOME PESSOAL ÁTONO pode, assim, ser um marcador de reflexividade [...] ou integrar o verbo (nesta obra, designado “verbo pronominal”) com que se combina (**valor inerente**):
>
> [...]
>
> Como exemplos de verbos com **pronome *se* inerente**, poderiam apresentar-se os seguinte: *admirar-se, apaixonar-se, arrepender-se, atrever-se,  casar-se, enganar-se, esforçar-se, esquecer-se, indignar-se, lembrar-se, orgulhar-se, queixar-se, rir-se, **suicidar-se**, zangar-se*.

Na prática podemos distinguir o ***se*** reflexo do inerente, porque podemos reforçar o reflexo com *a mim mesmo, a ti mesmo*, etc., enquanto o inerente não pode ser assim reforçado: *conhece-te a ti mesmo*, mas não *riu-se a si mesmo* ou *suicidou-se a si mesmo* (embora eu diga *suicidou-se a si mesmo* por brincadeira).

Já ha algumas perguntas que abordam esta questão do ***se*** inerente versus reflexo: [arrepender-se é um verbo reflexivo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/arrepender-se-%C3%A9-um-verbo-reflexivo) e [the real meaning of ‘esquecer’](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/the-real-meaning-of-esquecer).

---

É verdade que de acordo com o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) *suicidar-se* vem de *suicida*, formado por *sui* + *cida*, por analogia com *homicida*, e *sui* é o genitivo latino do pronome reflexivo *se* e *-cida* é o pospositivo latino que significa ‘que mata, que corta, que deita abaixo’. Logo poderíamos ser tentados a dizer que *suicidar* já significa ‘matar-se a si mesmo’. Mas isto seria incorrer numa falácia etimológica (ver na [wikipédia em espanhol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falacia_etimol%C3%B3gica)), isto é, pensar erradamente que o significado de uma palavra é determinado pela sua origem. Por essa ordem de ideias, *comigo* também seria redundante, já que vem em última análise de *com* + o latim *mecum* [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/comigo), e *mecum* já significava ‘com mim’.

Comment: Como já dizia o Asterix, aqueles romanos deviam ser loucos. Falavam ao contrário: onde já se viu *mim com* (*mecum*)!?

Answer (score 5):

Sim, a princípio é redundante, mas de uso consagrado: a forma com o "se" [é a correta](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/saiba-a-maneira-correta-de-empregar-o-pronome-reflexivo-se.html).

Convém notar, no entanto, que, conforme esclarece muito bem a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5468/2764) de Jacinto, por ser parte intrínseca do verbo, sem conter qualquer sentido reflexivo, o "se" é uma redundância apenas aparente.

Comment: Compreendo e concordo com o espírito (+1), mas não concordo totalmente. Vê a minha resposta (quando estiver pronta).

Comment: Na verdade, @Jacinto, tua resposta é muito melhor (inclusive atualizei a minha). Espero que o OP também reconheça isto e a aceite.

Comment: Eh pá, obrigado; uma pessoa fica emocionada :) -- incluí uma nota acerca da falácia etimológica.

Answer (score -1):

A palavra suicídio vem do latim, sendo formada por sui (= de si, a si) e cídio (= matar), significando matar a si mesmo. Logo, a grafia suicidar-se, embora seja utilizada, não parece ser a mais correta. A prova é que o verbete suicidar-se não consta do Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa (VOLP), da Academia Brasileira de Letras.