# "Ele se auto-proclamou" é gramatical ? É aceitável na língua escrita e falada?

Tags: gramática, pronomes-reflexivos, redundâncias

Tenho ouvido com frequência na televisão que "Juan Guaidó se auto-proclamou presidente da Venezuela", uma redundância que não soa bem aos meus ouvidos.  Tenho ouvido tanto que venho questionar se é gramaticalmente correto dizer e escrever **"ele se auto-proclamou"** e **"ele se auto-mutilou"**, ao invés de **"ele se proclamou"** e **"ele se mutilou"**.

Uma rápida busca no Google Books mostra:

- 1.300 resultados para "ele se mutilou" e apenas 237 para "ele se auto-mutilou"
- Já com o verbo proclamar, a coisa muda um pouco de figura.  Encontrei 16.000 resultados para "ele se proclamou" e 9.630 para "ele se autoproclamou"

Encontrei também três grafias para a expressão: autoproclamou, auto-proclamou e auto proclamou.

Comment: O VOLP não reconhece *autoproclamar*. *Auto-proclamar* está incorreto, pois deve-se usar o hífen com o prefixo *auto* + palavras iniciadas por *h* ou *o*. Sobre a partícula *se*, parece-me que é um pronome reflexivo. O verbo *autoproclamar* existe e é semelhante ao *proclamar*.

Comment: **Autoproclamar** = Fazer o anúncio sem consultar outrem. Ex.: Zé de Abreu autoproclamou-se presidente do Brasil. 

**Proclamar** = Fazer o anúncio ou torná-lo público. Ex.: Guaidó proclamou-se presidente da Venezuela.

Comment: Para mim, a principal diferença está em consultar as pessoas. O Guaidó teve apoio para fazer este ato. O Zé de Abreu, por outro lado, fez o mesmo ato, porém sem consultas, sem apoios e de modo surpresa, logo eu usaria *autoproclamar* para o Zé de Abreu e *proclamar* para o Guaidó. P.S.: Não se é uma boa resposta, mas se alguém puder complementar no campo de respostas, agradeço.

Comment: Relacionada: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5464/se-suicidar-%c3%a9-redundante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos esses quatro verbos existem, e basicamente *autoproclamar-se* é o mesmo que *proclamar-se* e *automutilar-se* é (aproximadamente?) o mesmo que *mutilar-se*. Mas ao eliminarmos o *auto*- podemos perder ênfase ou até mesmo clareza.

### *Proclamar-se* e *Autoproclamar-se*

*Proclamar* tem vários usos. Pode-se proclamar as boas novas ou a independência do país; mas o que no interessa é *proclama-se*, que os dicionários definem como:

Academia das Ciências de Lisboa

> **proclamar** […] **4**. +-se. Assumir por sua própria iniciativa uma função; atribuir-se um cargo por autoridade própria. *Proclamou-se secretária da direção*.

Houaiss

> **proclamar** […] **4** *transitivo direto predicativo e pronominal* (1563-1570) atribuir(-se) título ou posto; intitular-se; aclamar-se […] <*o usurpador proclamou-se rei*>

Temos definições semelhantes no [Michaelis, aceção 3](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/proclamar/), [Aulete, 5 & 6](http://www.aulete.com.br/proclamar) e [Priberam, 6](https://dicionario.priberam.org/proclamar); este último dá *proclamar-se* como [*arvorar-se em*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/arvorar-se), que é  “atribuir(-se) título, cargo, condição ou qualidade.”

Tudo isto coincide exatamente com a definição de *autoproclamar-se* no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/autoproclamar-se), o único dicionário que tem um definição desenvolvida e precisa:

> [**Autoproclamar-se**](http://www.aulete.com.br/autoproclamar-se)
> **1**. Atribuir a si mesmo posição, dignidade, cargo ou função e anunciá-lo publicamente; proclamar a si mesmo: *Sem consultar ninguém, autoproclamou-se soberano vitalício do país. : Na falta de uma decisão do tribunal desportivo, os dois clubes autoproclamaram-se campeões*

O dicionário da Academia diz apenas que é “proclamar-se a si mesmo”; o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/autoproclamar) diz que é “apresentar em público uma decisão unilateral”; vago, porque, por exemplo, quando um professor anuncia unilateralmente um teste, não se está a autoproclamar. O Houaiss e o Michaelis não têm *autoproclamar-se*.

Portanto, uma pessoa ao proclamar-se presidente ou outra coisa, não se limita a anunciar que ocupa agora um certo cargo ou posição; atribui-se a si mesma esse cargo ou posição. O *auto-* em *autoproclamar-se* simplesmente enfatiza esse facto.

### *Mutilar-se* e *Automutilar-se*

Vejamos *mutilar-se* no dicionários (só aceções relevantes)

Houaiss:
**mutilar** *v*. (1686 cf. AVSerm) **1** *transitivo direto e pronominal* causar mutilação em (alguém ou si próprio); cortar(-se); retalhar(-se) […] <*a faca mutilou-lhe o pé*> <*ao mutilar-se com a tesoura de podar relva, quase perdeu os dedos da mão*>

[Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/mutilar)
**1.** Privar de membro ou parte do corpo a (outrem ou si mesmo) [transitivo direto: […] *Mutilou-se todo num acesso de loucura*]

O [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/mutilar/) diz a mesma coisa. Por sua vez, [*automutilar*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/automutilar), encontrei apenas no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/automutilar), que diz simplesmente

> **automutilar** […] mutilar-se a si mesmo

O Priberam emprega *mutilar-se* nesta definição, mas esquece-se de explicitar este uso no verbete [*mutilar*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mutilar).

Portanto, os dicionários não apontam qualquer diferença entre *automutilar-se* e *mutilar-se*. No entanto na minha sensibilidade, se eu ouvir *o jovem automutilou-se*, eu vou presumir que foi deliberado, a menos que haja no contexto alguma sugestão do contrário. Já em *o jovem mutilou-se*, eu vou no mínimo admitir a possibilidade de ter sido acidental.

### Grafia

A grafia oficial é *autoproclamar* e *automutilar* quer no Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, quer na ortografia anterior. Com o pseudoprefixo *auto*- só se emprega hífen quando o segundo elemento começa por **o** ou **h** ([AO 90, base XVI](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990)). Não encontrei verbos em que isso acontecesse, por isso servem de exemplo [auto-observação](https://dicionario.priberam.org/auto-observa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [auto-hipnose](https://dicionario.priberam.org/auto-hipnose)

Na grafia anterior ao AO90, usava-se hífen também quando o segundo elemento começasse por qualquer outra vogal, ou por **r** ou **s**; na grafia atual, duplica-se o **r** ou **s**. O Priberam permite comparar as duas grafias (selecionando essa opção nas preferências): [autoadministrar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/autoadministrar), [autorretratar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/autorretratar), [autossugestionar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/autossugestionar).

Comment: "No entanto na minha sensibilidade, se eu ouvir o jovem automutilou-se, eu vou presumir..."  Percebo que eu também entenderia assim.

Answer (score 6):

**PROCLAMAR x AUTOPROCLAMAR**

Guardado o devido respeito aos recentes eventos políticos na Venezuela, de Juan Guidó ter proclamado-se ou autoproclamado-se, ou ainda manifestações em torno disto como o caso do Zé de Abreu ter proclamado-se ou autoproclamado-se, essa discussão pode estar fora do escopo deste fórum, contudo, o fato é que os verbos possuem significados diferentes:

- ***Proclamar***: Anunciar/publicar ([priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/proclamar))
- ***Autoproclamar***: Anunciar/publicar uma decisão unilateral ([priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/autoproclamar))

O que talvez gere mais confusão ainda é que ambos, além de transitivos, são também **verbos pronominais**, portanto as formas abaixo estão corretas:

- ***Proclamou-se***: Se anunciar a público. *Exemplo: A professora Márcia proclamou-se a nova coordenadora assim que eleita pela maioria dos professores.*
- ***Autoproclamou-se***: Se anunciar a público sob uma decisão unilateral. *Exemplo: No meu departamento não tínhamos pessoas interessadas em preparar o café, mas ontem o José se autoproclamou o responsável por fazer o café diariamente pela manhã"*

**MUTILAR x AUTOMUTILAR:**

- ***Mutilar***: Verbo exclusivamente transitivo
- ***Automutilar***: Verbo exclusivamente pronominal

Portanto, "mutilar-se" por definição é incorreto e para usar de forma pronominal seria "automutilar-se".

Soa um pleonasmo ou redundante, de fato, por isso acredito que haja alguma história "evolutiva" parecido como o caso do verbo também pronominal "suicidar-se": https://cbn.globoradio.globo.com/media/audio/195521/cometer-suicidio-praticar-suicidio-ou-suicidar-se.htm

Comment: O que dizer de "mutilar", "auto-mutilar"  (corrigido para duas palavras pelo meu corretor)

Comment: @Centaurus: Infelizmente perdi o texto original, editei fora do stackexchange e na hora de copiar acabei perdendo. Inclui assim mesmo a diferença básica (mutilar 
 automutilar) sem os exemplos e outros detalhes que eu tinha elaborado..

Comment: Luciano, um só dicionário pode ser insuficiente: Vários dicionários registam *mutiilar-se:* "*ao mutilar-se com a tesoura de podar relva, quase perdeu os dedos da mão*" (Houaiss). Em princípio qualquer verbo transitivo direto admite o *se* como objeto direto. Mesmo sendo materialmente impossível, por exemplo, uma gata parir-se a si mesma, *parir-se* é linguisticamente possível.